# Not able to load avro data into hive table

Tags: java, hive

I am doing some analysis on Twitter data. The data is in Avro format and I want to load this data into hive table. I am creating an external table to load the data but I am getting an EOFException. I am not able to get anything. Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: please add the query that you are trying to your question, so that your problem can be understood in clear

Comment: What's the create table command you're using on the table.  There's not enough information here to answer your question.